# Remove the observer using the handle in Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

I have the following case. The root controller is `UITabViewController`. There is a `ProfileViewController`, in it I make an observer that users started to be friends (and then the screen functions change). `ProfileViewController` can be opened with 4 tabs out of 5, and so the current user can open the screen with the same user in four places. In previous versions, when ProfileViewController opened in one place, I deleted the observer in deinit and did the deletion just by `ref.removeAllObservers()`, now when the user case is such, I started using handle and delete observer in viewDidDisappear. I would like to demonstrate the code to find out whether it can be improved and whether I'm doing it right in this situation.

I call this function in viewWillAppear

```
   fileprivate func firObserve(_ isObserve: Bool) {
        guard let _user = user else { return }
        FIRFriendsDatabaseManager.shared.observeSpecificUserFriendshipStart(observer: self, isObserve: isObserve, userID: _user.id, success: { [weak self] (friendModel) in
        }) { (error) in

        }
    }
```

This is in the FIRFriendsDatabaseManager

```
fileprivate var observeSpecificUserFriendshipStartDict = [AnyHashable : UInt]()


func observeSpecificUserFriendshipStart(observer: Any, isObserve: Bool, userID: String, success: ((_ friendModel: FriendModel) -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        let realmManager = RealmManager()
        guard let currentUserID = realmManager.getCurrentUser()?.id else { return }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let specificUserFriendRef = Database.database().reference().child(MainGateways.friends.description).child(currentUserID).child(SubGateways.userFriends.description).queryOrdered(byChild: "friendID").queryEqual(toValue: userID)

            if !isObserve {
                guard let observerHashable = observer as? AnyHashable else { return }
                if let handle = self.observeSpecificUserFriendshipStartDict[observerHashable] {
                    self.observeSpecificUserFriendshipStartDict[observerHashable] = nil
                    specificUserFriendRef.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
                    debugPrint("removed handle", handle)
                }
                return
            }

            var handle: UInt = 0

            handle = specificUserFriendRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                    return
                }
                guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
                guard let friendModel = Mapper<FriendModel>().map(JSON: dict) else { return }

                if friendModel.friendID == userID {
                    success?(friendModel)
                }
            }, withCancel: { (error) in
                fail?(error)
            })

            guard let observerHashable = observer as? AnyHashable else { return }
            self.observeSpecificUserFriendshipStartDict[observerHashable] = handle
        }
    }
```

Comment: So from what I understand, your code is functioning properly and your question is just: 'Is there a better way to do this than what I've done?' If this is correct. Here is my feedback. Your logic seems reasonable to me, considering what you've described you want to accomplish. And as a general point of feedback on your code `observeSpecificUserFriendshipStart` could be refactored to be much more readable.

Comment: @Doug Yes, you correctly understood the question, I most do not like it, that I store links to controllers in the dictionary and so I thought maybe there is an option better)

Comment: @Doug In this variant, there is one big disadvantage, that for example, if there is any case to delete observers in deinit, then the manager gets a link to the controller in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your implementation of maintaining a reference to each viewController, I would consider moving the logic to an extension of the viewController itself.

And if you'd like to avoid calling `ref.removeAllObservers()` like you were previously, and assuming that there is just one of these listeners per viewController. I'd make the listener ref a variable on the view controller.

This way everything is contained to just the viewController. It also is potentially a good candidate for creating a protocol if other types of viewControllers will be doing similar types of management of listeners.